# How should I handle item 'type' Strings in my code, so they are consistent across applications?

Tags: java, static

This might seem like a dumb question, but it's not readily apparent to me how this should be handled in java code:

I have a number of devices that interact with my system via API's. They each have a type, for example TV, SmartPhone, Laptop.
My code needs to do a number of different things depending on this type. This is the case for a number of other servers in the system.
Records relating to each device are stored in the database, including the type.

Currently what I'm doing is having a static class with references to each type, like this:

`DeviceType.SMART_PHONE`

which I then use all over the place. Each project may have a class like this. 
So it's used in the manner of:

```
if(device.getType().equals(DeviceType.SMART_PHONE){
    // stuff happens
}
```

Sometimes I will have the public static variables in a class that uses them, so in the device object itself.

What is the best practice for stuff like this?

Comment: Look into coding to an interface.  Perhaps you can have a single interface to represent all devices, and then provide implementations for each device.

Comment: This is an option I have been considering, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a *strategy pattern* to me as you are doing something different for each `DeviceType`. In such a case you could have a common interface that would perform the `stuff happens` (whatever that is). For example:

```
// if you have java-8, this could be replaced with java.util.Consumer for example
interface Handler {
    public void handle();
}
```

then you could create all the needed Handlers.

```
static class SmartPhoneHandler implements Handler {
     public void handle(){
        // handle smart phone logic here
     }
}
```

You would need to register these to a `Map`:

```
Map<DeviceType, Handler> strategies = new HashMap<>(); // or EnumMap in case DeviceType is an enum
strategies.put(DeviceType.SmartPhone, new SmartPhoneHandler());
// all others like this
```

later usage would be :

```
strategies.get(device.getType()).handle()
```

If you need some parameters as input for the handle method - you should create another holder called `StrategyContext` that would take as input the needed parameters, for example:

```
 static class StrategyContext {
     private final int deviceId; // for example
     // .... constructor/getters 
 }
```

and thus your `handle` method would change to:

```
handle(StrategyContext context)
```

Comment: This is a really interesting approach, I'm going to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @bot_bot sure, take a look, we use this approach in production quite a lot btw

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to create enum 'DeviceType' with all the types defined.
This way you can make sure that these static finals won't be everywhere in the project. 
This will also prevent silly spelling mistakes or other mistakes associated with String constants defined all over the project.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I neglected to mention, the other systems and databases I interact with are already using `String`s, so from what I've been reading elsewhere the cost of converting from `String` to `Enum` and back again mitigates the benefits of using `Enum`. There is no way I can change the info in the databases.